# How do I trigger a click event on a disabled button element (using pure vanilla JS)?

Tags: javascript, modularity, typescript

I have this event: `this.show.onclick = this.sendData.bind(this);`

in my `bindEvents()` function:

```js
bindEvents: function() {

    var that = this;

    // On click "Show" BTN
    this.show.onclick = this.sendData.bind(this);

    // On Change inputs
    this.$form.change(function(){
        that.updateDatesInputs(this);
    });
},
```

That runs this:

```js
sendData: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let that                = this;

    console.log(this.show.disabled);
    if (this.show.disabled) {
        alert('a disabled button has just been clicked!');
        this.showErrorDiv("Please select a new date range.");
    } else {

        $.ajax({
                    ....
            }
        });

        that.dataDisplayed = true;
}
```

Clicking on my "show" button-element doesn't activate any click event. All I found googling this is that jQuery can fix it, but I want to use vanilla JS.

How can I trigger an event on a disabled element so that my alert will get executed using only pure JS?

Comment: `How can I trigger an event on a disabled element` You can't. Disabled elements do not raise any events whatsoever. If you need this behaviour you'll have to 'fake' the disable state using CSS.

Comment: @Rick Sanchez did you try $(this).trigger( "click" );

Comment: Couldn’t you wrap the disabled button on a doc that isn’t disabled, then listen for a click on that div?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done, nor should it for accessibility reasons. Someone who navigates with a keyboard can never get to the button to interact with it.